# How can we pass 2 values in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't pass the selected value to the listing page. When I select an option and click search, a default value passing to listing page. (Default value: last added value)

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from jobregestation order by id");

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['JobName'];
    echo "<option value=" . $id . ">" . $name . "</option>";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more detail like html form and this above page full code\

Comment: Also, show us what the generated select box looks like.

Comment: Removed please help me, and replace polite ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking forward something like that ?

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // worked when click on serarch button

    echo $_POST['exampleName'];
}
?>
<form action="" method='post'>
<select name="exampleName">
<?php
   $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from jobregestation order by id");
   while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
       $id = $row['id'];
       $name = $row['JobName'];
       echo "<option value=" . $id . ">" . $name . "</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>

</form>
```

Comment: this is not valid php

Comment: Sorry ! i don't get you . What are you talking about valid. It's old coding pattern of PHP. Whatever i just try to help as far i understood his question.

Comment: Yeap . i understood where was the problem ?  It was my mistake when i cut the code from the question .Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<?php
foreach ($sql->fetch_assoc() as $key=>$value)
{
echo "<option value = " .$value['id'] . ">" .$value['Jobname]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

This should work.